# How to grab Li's within Ul's

Tags: jquery, html

I have the below HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>hello</li>
    <ul>
        <li>Hello world1</li>
        <li>Hello world2</li>
    </ul>
    <li>bye</li>
</ul>
```

I want to grab the inner Li's i.e. The output will be

```
Hello world1
Hello world2
```

I tried as

```
$('ul > ul > li').css("background", "green");​​​​​​​​​​
```

But the selector formation might be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner `<ul>` is not direct child of outer `<ul>` so, the [child selector `>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) selector will not work.

Use [descendant selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors)

```
$('ul ul > li')
```

```js
$('ul ul > li').css('color', 'green');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
 <li>hello</li>   
      <ul>
          <li>Hello world1</li>
          <li>Hello world2</li>
       </ul>  
 <li>bye</li>
</ul>
```

---

> I want to grab the inner Li's i.e. The output will be
>
> > Hello world1
> >
> > Hello world2

```js
$('ul ul > li').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>hello</li>
  <ul>
    <li>Hello world1</li>
    <li>Hello world2</li>
  </ul>
  <li>bye</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select like shown below

```
$('ul ul li').css('color','red')
```

**Working Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('ul ul li').css('color','red')
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
 <li>hello</li>   
      <ul>
          <li>Hello world1</li>
          <li>Hello world2</li>
       </ul>  
 <li>bye</li>
</ul>
```

**OR**

You can select like shown below

```
$('ul').find('ul li').css('color','red')
```

**Working Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('ul').find('ul li').css('color','red')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>hello</li>
    <ul>
        <li>Hello world1</li>
        <li>Hello world2</li>
    </ul>
    <li>bye</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

For optimal use add a class to the inner ul

```
<ul>
    <li>hello</li>
    <ul class="inner-ul">
        <li>Hello world1</li>
        <li>Hello world2</li>
    </ul>
    <li>bye</li>
</ul>
```

js:

```
$('.inner-ul').css("background", "green");​​​​​​​​​​
```